# Is there any way to permanently lock an answer?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, spam

A particular answer of mine, [Coin Betting Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33530/7933), is being regularly edited as vandalism. I can only assume this particular question and answer are somehow magnets for spam due to the "betting" word. It gets spammy vandalism seemingly every other month or so, and it's just annoying.

(The vandalism is always rejected - the review process is working.)

By the way, is this common - are the spammy edits concentrated on a few questions/answers? How common is this?

Just for completeness, the most recent edit removed all my content and replaced it with the text:

```
Thank you for share! [url=... spam URL ...]louboutin shoes on sale[/url]
```

This is the usual form of the edit: complete deletion of the content, then replacement with a trivial spam message.

Comment: The ♦-mods can lock (and unlock) posts (whole questions or individual answers).  Keep in mind that a locked post does not admit any changes (except by a few select individuals): no edits, no comments, and no votes. (see [MSO locked posts FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/214632).) I would actually wait on suggesting that your post be locked. As spammy suggested edits are rejected, the IP addresses associated to these edits get closer to being banned.  (See [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224547/214632), again.)

Comment: I'm trying to get someone higher up to provide some more information on this case. Your answer is the only post on that question that has received spammy suggested edits (likely because it is the highest voted post), but I can't see any details about the suggested edits beyond some very basic info.

Comment: Can you give an example or two of such spammy edits?

Comment: @Asaf: Here are the two most recent examples: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/182588), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/181415).

Comment: @Arthur: It might be the SE review system taking audits one step further. :-P

Comment: Try to make the post longer than 400 characters, after that threshold any anonymous suggested edit that radically changes the post is automatically rejected.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks, I've slightly improved formatting and gone over 400 characters by adding some \left\right pairs. Hopefully, that will reduce the frequency.

Comment: So, I guess that bot is probably vandalizing lots of replies, but the change is automatically rejected except in replies under 400 characters.

Comment: A quick sampling of my own answers indicates that I have plenty of them shorter than 400 characters. It certainly could be one part of the reason, but it can hardly be the primary selection criterion. @GEdgar

Comment: Relevant feature request (under review): [Automatically reject suggested edits where edit summary is an email address](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207837/251274)